# fpdf and empty query results

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm designing a system which creates a class of reports, that are generated by selecting between two date type inputs, and simply by clicking on a "generate" button which executes a query.

If the query does not generate any results, and the table or columns are empty because there were no records registered between those two dates, could I make fpdf write a message in the page saying a message like "no records"? Just below the header of the table. Because, currently, when you can not find a record, it simply shows the blank table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how far you've got or if you're executing your SQL in the same FPDF script or recieving them from another script, or if you're writing the document inside functions or classes like $pdf->Body(), etc

I'll asume a lot, maybe too much, but let's say you have your code working in the case there are results. It's something like this:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    //fill the table with results
} else {
    $pdf -> Write (10,'No results to show'); //10 is line height
}
```

...or Cell
...or $this->Write if you are calling FPDF from inside its Body

Comment: [Here's my code](https://justpaste.it/1jmp7) hope you can see things clearer with this. It's not too long.

Comment: @JoseFermin, great, give me an hour to have dinner and I'll check it out.

Comment: What I did is very simple: It prints every record. If no records were written, I print a line saying "no records to show"

Comment: Dude, thank u so much. It worked! Thank you for taking your time and helping me w/ this issue.